# OpenGL Compute Shader Shared Maximum

Tags: opengl, shader, glsl

I'm working on an OpenGL compute shader in which each work item results in a single number output I'll call x, as well as a struct output with more information, I'll call y. What I would like is a single output for each work group being the y of the work item with the maximum x.

Now I'm aware of the GLSL atomic operations and I believe I could easily get the maximum x, but I'm having trouble thinking of how to get the y associated with the maximum x. I could, in the compute shader, do a conditional right after I check for maximum x to check if x changed and change y accordingly, but I believe there is no guarantee that no other work item has replaced the maximum x at that point. I think this might be possible with memory barriers but I'm having trouble figuring out if it really is.

So I guess my question is, is there an established method to do something like this? Am I perhaps over complicating it? Is there a way, with memory barriers, to create critical section-like behavior? Do I need to do the maximums on the CPU or in another serial compute shader?

Comment: "*What I would like is a single output for each work group being the y of the work item with the maximum x.*" What should happen if two work items produce the same `x`?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what the problem here is. If you can determine which work item gave the maximum `x`, then can you not just fetch the `y` value it generated?

Comment: I guess my current thinking is I would not like to store each y in order to decide after all the work items have finished and would like to just have it swap out the y as the work items are run. This may not be the correct way to do it and I'm open to that. Regarding two work items producing the same x, in my application, that should be inconsequential which is decided to be the new maximum.

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out which thread has the max value by modifying x: pack gl_LocalInvocationIndex in the least significant bits of x. The number of bits you need for the index depends on your group size.

If you need all 32 bits of x then I suggest using 2 compute shaders - first record max per group. Then compute x again and compare.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it: first find the maximum x using atomics on a shared variable. Then, have each thread compare its local version of x to the found maximum, and store to y only if they are equal.

```
shared uint x, y;
...
uint localX, localY;
// each thread computes its localX and localY
atomicMax(x, localX);
barrier();  // ensure all threads have done the atomicMax before going on
if (x == localX)
{
    atomicExchange(y, localY);
}
barrier();
// now you can read the final x and y values
```

This should work even if there are multiple threads with the same maximum value of `x`, as the stores to `y` are atomic, so you'll just end up with an arbitrary one of them "winning".

A variation on this, which may be useful if `y` is a larger struct of multiple pieces of data and therefore can't be atomically stored natively, is to use the local invocation index to pick the "winning" thread.

```
shared uint x, winningThread;
shared MyStruct y;
...
uint localX;
MyStruct localY;
// each thread computes its localX and localY
atomicMax(x, localX);
barrier();  // ensure all threads have done the atomicMax before going on
if (x == localX)
{
    atomicExchange(winningThread, gl_LocalInvocationIndex);
}
barrier();
if (winningThread == gl_LocalInvocationIndex)
{
    y = localY;  // only one thread will ever do this store, so doesn't need to be atomic
}
barrier();
// now you can read the final x and y values
```